# Passing Dictionary ByRef Into a Private Sub in excel VBA userform module gives ByRef type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, userform, byref

I am creating a userform that collects different sets of information into different Dictionaries for processing.
The Dictionaries are declared at the userform module level, and initialised in another procedure on activation of the userform.
In order to streamline my code, I have a subroutine that inserts items into appropriate dictionaries.
I have added Microsoft Scripting Runtime to VBA References
Here are the code examples

At the userform module declaration

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Dim Ref_Dict, Client_Dict, Service_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
```

The Dictionaries are initialised within another procedure in the same module. This module is called on activation of the form. Part of the activation module is

```
Set Ref_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set Client_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set Service_Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

This is the Procedure that inserts items into appropriate dictionary

```
Private Sub Update_Dict(ByRef Dict As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal Item As Variant, ByVal Key As Variant)
Dict(Key) = Item
End Sub
```

The above procedure is called from Textbox or ComboBox _AfterUpdate procedure (as the case may be) eg

```
Private Sub ComboBox_1_AfterUpdate()
Dim Item, Key As Variant
Item = Me.ComboBox_1.Value
Key = "Name"
Update_Dict Ref_Dict, Item, Key
End Sub
```

Entering a value into ComboBox_1 throws up error "ByRef Arguement type mismatch.

However, If I replicate the same scenario in a regular module, It runs perfectly.
Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you declared it on a module-level, then why are you even passing it as an argument to begin with within the same module?

Comment: `Ref_Dict` and  `Client_Dict` are declared as Variant in that code.

Comment: I am passing it as an argument because I want to tell the procedure which of the dictionaries (there are actually up to 8 of them) it should add the provided Item to using the provided key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a victim of a typical VBA pitfall.

AS Rory wrote in the comments, when you write

```
Dim Ref_Dict, Client_Dict, Service_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
```

you declare only `Service_Dict` as a Dictionary. The other two variables are declared as `Variant`. As a `Variant` can contain *anything* (any data type), you can assign a dictionary object to it as you do in your activation routine.

However, a `Variant` holding a Dictionary is *not the same* as a Dictionary, therefore you get the "Type Mismatch" error.

Simple to correct, provide the data type for all of your variables:

```
Dim Ref_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary, Client_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary, Service_Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: That is not the problem.  I devclared Item and type as variant because they could be any data type. The type mismatch error is actually on the dictionary object itself.

Comment: @draustine You've missed the point, I'm afraid. Please read this answer again and *try* the suggested solution.

Comment: @draustine I'm not talking about `item` and `key`. I am talking about `Ref_Dict` and `Client_Dict`. You need to specify the type for every variable, else VBA will assume Variant.

Comment: It is also correct to declare multiple variables of the type together, separating them by ", " eg 
```
Dim A, b, c, d As Integer
~~~

Comment: No. That's what Rory and I tried to explain: `Dim a, b, c, d As Integer` declare a, b and c as Variant and only d as Integer. As I wrote: A typical pitfall in VBA

Comment: Thank you @Rory and FunThomas. Wao I didn't know this before. Actually, I am a self-taught excel VBA developer. Thank you. I declared each variable individually, and that solved the problem.